# I'm unable to run a project in Android Studio 3 using a connected device

Tags: java, android, cordova

When I try to run a project in my Android device (7.0.0) using Android Studio 3 this error shows up:

```
Error:Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':debugCompileClasspath'.
>   Could not resolve project :CordovaLib.
>        Required by:
>            project :
>   Project : declares a dependency from configuration 'debugCompile' to configuration 'debug' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :CordovaLib.

I can't find anything relevant to this problem